# iphone code sining error

Tags: iphone

i tried to build a iphone application. create certificate every thing.

then i got a error   that is

Checking Dependencies
Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.max.iphoneTestingCode' could not be found

max is our company name..

1) where is we mention bundle identifer.?

2) how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the App ID in the program portal with the identifier in your app.

Ie. if your profile is `#ID#.com.foo.*` and you try to sign `com.bar.bash`, it won't work, but com.foo.bash should work.

So, make sure that the profile in the program portal has com.max.iphoneTestingCode as the identifier or it's something that matches like `*`

The bundle identifier is in Target Bar > Get Info > Properties > Identifier.